# How to build spring boot app in Intellij IDEA in a docker image within the IDE?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, intellij-idea

I need to replicate the build in our CI/CD tool in the dev workstations of the developers by making Intellij IDEA build within a docker container instead of the current system. Is this doable? I find similar threads with launching the app inside (that i don't need), i need it only as a build environment. I already have the Docker plugin installed but i fail to see how to make it as a build environment.

I have installed the docker plugin, prepared the image. I have docker installed on the workstation.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: I am trying to build my app inside a docker container every build, as opposed to building on the workstation itself. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. You would need to run maven inside the Dockerfile

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications into you question post. Don't hide them in the comments.

Comment: I have stated everything i want to ask in the right order. I need to launch a container WHEN click to build my app INSIDE IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting something like this?

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine as build
WORKDIR /workspace/app

COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src

RUN ./mvnw package -DskipTests

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=/workspace/app/target/dependency
COPY --from=build  /workspace/app/${JAR_FILE} /app/
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /app.jar ${0} ${@}"]
```

You can use the maven container as a build container to save maven installation time in case it takes.

Comment: you should replace install with package. It' makes no sense

Comment: and you probably need to copy more than just the src directory

Comment: i know how to do the Dockerfile. I need to make it automatic for builds inside Intellij Idea versus building on the actual host.